# Nested lookup types in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, types, nested

Given type

```
type X = {
  a: {
    b: {
      c: string;
    };
  };
};
```

I would expect

```
type Y = {
  [k in keyof X]: {
    [j in keyof X[k]]: X[k][j]['c'];
  };
};
```

to give me

```
{
  a: {
    b: string;
  };
};
```

However, I get error `ts2536: "Type 'c' cannot be used to index type 'X[k][j]'` here. But that is wrong, isn't it?

So why does the error happen and what could I do to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The expression `X[k][j]` seems to be too complicated for TypeScript to remember all the relations between `X`, `k` and `j`. So it does not know that `X[k][j]` must have a property `c`.

We can help TypeScript accept this by adding an addtional check before indexing `X`.

```
type Y = {
  [k in keyof X]: {
    [j in keyof X[k]]: X[k][j] extends { c: any } ? X[k][j]['c'] : never;
  };
};
```

This extra check will always be true but it tells TypeScript that `X[k][j]` must have a property `c` in the true branch.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.8.0-dev.20220609&ssl=13&ssc=3&pln=9&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAGlC8UDeAoKUCGAuZb1QCMdV98BjHAZ2ACcBLAOwHMBuPdAXzc7a5RVCQoATQS50AbQDWURlCkQQAewBmsALrF2UCQCtZDeYtWxp6zaanq96qBAAewCAwAmlZFAqYGIKBygA-JbWutYA5GRhtjgMEABuEDTcfrwsQA)

---

This is a bit shorter but also has the same effect:

```
type Y = {
  [k in keyof X]: {
    [j in keyof X[k]]: (X[k][j] & { c: any })['c'];
  };
};
```

Comment: But `c` would just be `any` then, wouldn't it? But we can fix this of course in your first approach by `X[k][j] extends { c: infer T } ? T : never`.

Comment: No, if you hover over `Y` you see that everything works as expected. `extends { c: any }` is only a constraint which forces TypeScript to acknowledge that it is an object with a property `c`. The real type of `c` will be evaluated with `['c']`

Comment: using `infer T` works too, but it leads to the same result